# What Access 2010 Ace DAO libraryfiles do I need for VB6 connection

Tags: ms-access, dao

Hello and thank you for reading/helping :).

I have an application that was created with VB6 using MS Access 2003 with DAO 3.6.

Upgrading the Access database to 2010 has been accomplished and I am using the ACE OFFICE 14.0 DAO Library object MSACC.OLB. I have everything working in my dev environment.

My question is what files do I need to place in an installer to make the connection work on a machine that does not have Office 2007/2010 installed?

I have used the AccessDatabaseEngine.exe located here :
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255
which does work and my app works great and functions, but installing this exe during an installation is not my ideal process.

I would like to be able to just pull the files that are required for the connection to work and drop them in place then register them (assuming it is that easy) during an install of my app.

I have searched google/forums for hours, I even logged all the files used by the exe and tried dropping them in place one by one and manually registering them but my app does not work so far.

any help is appreciated

Comment: Does the benefit of replicating the AccessDatabaseEngine.exe installer really outweigh the costs?  It seems to me that the benefit is pretty slight: a cleaner installation experience for your end user.  The costs are pretty significant: your time, your headaches.  There's also increased risk: what if you get something wrong?

Comment: I have to agree, I would just install ACE or include it in part of your install package (chain it into the msi install). JET the previous data engine was installed by default from windows 98SE up to win7. So JET been included with windows for more than 10 years now and perhaps you stick to older JET? I would only use ACE if you need new features like stored procedures + database triggers. I don't see why some chain install is too problematic here and  I can't see this being any more hassle than installing any file based data engine. Perhaps stick to older JET which is included with windows?

Comment: thank you for the responses, true after pondering this yesterday and more searching/trial and error of course I decided it is most likely better to just include the msi installers. Oh and the reason for going forward with ACE is due to the problems Windows 7 has with Access found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2553116

Comment: ... And MSACC.OLB is NOT a DAO library object. It is a MicroSoft ACCess declaration object (an interface containing no code). Adding a MSACC.OLB dependency was probably a mistake. That's probably not what you should be using. Actually, moving to ACE was probably a mistake-- you didn't notice that the hotfix you referenced was for ACE? -- but given ACE, MSACC.OLB is still probably not where you should be.